# How to query rows with distinct column values grouped by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that counts (using SUM) separated groups depending on a column value, and then groups them by months. I think a better explanation would be to share the concept.

Consider this table (myTable):

```
Id       ItemID    Color           CreatedDate
--------------------------------------------------
1          2        Red          someDateTimeStamp
2          3        Blue         someDateTimeStamp
3          4        Green        someDateTimeStamp
4          5        Blue         someDateTimeStamp
5          2        Red          someDateTimeStamp
6          3        Purple       someDateTimeStamp
7          2        Blue         someDateTimeStamp
8          3        Blue         someDateTimeStamp
9          3        Blue         someDateTimeStamp
```

So Id is the primary key, ItemID is a foreign key. Not that it is not obvious.

My query:

```
SELECT TOP 12 
    DateAdd(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, t.CreatedDate), 0) AS [Date],     
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.Color = 'Red' or t.Color = 'Green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS firstCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.Color = 'Blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS secondCount
FROM 
    myTable t
Group By 
    DateAdd(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, t.CreatedDate), 0)
ORDER BY 
    DateAdd(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, t.CreatedDate), 0)
```

This query counts the Colors and groups them by month for the last 12 months. It works fine and counts everything as expected, until I realized that I should not include the same [ItemID] per month. As you can see it can appear more than once at anytime, and I only need to count it once per month.

If the above table values all fall within the same month, my current query returns:

```
    Date                firstCount         secondCount
------------------------------------------------------
    someDateStamp           3                   5
```

What it should return:

```
    Date                firstCount         secondCount
 ------------------------------------------------------
    someDateStamp           2                   3
```

I first thought that I can use something like:

```
HAVING count(t.ItemID) = 1
```

but that obviously excludes all that are more than 1.

If any further explanation is required please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can this

1 Get distinct value in cte .

2 create rank()

sample

```
    ;with resut as  
    (
    select distinct  ItemID,   
                    Color,
                    DateAdd(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, t.CreatedDate), 0) AS [Date]
    from myTable t
    )

    SELECT TOP 12 
    [Date],
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.Color = 'Red' or t.Color = 'Green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS firstCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.Color = 'Blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS secondCount

    from resut t
    Group By [Date]
    order by [Date]
```

Comment: Thank you. This is great. To be honest I have never seen cte. Got some reading to do. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You could tweak the mytable:

...

```
 SELECT 
CreatedMonth,     
SUM(CASE WHEN t.Color = 'Red' or t.Color = 'Green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
AS firstCount,
SUM(CASE WHEN t.Color = 'Blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS secondCount

FROM
  ( select ItemID,Color,
    DateAdd(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CreatedDate), 0) as CreatedMonth
    from mytable 
    group by ItemID,Color,
    DateAdd(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CreatedDate), 0)) t
```

Group By
   t.CreatedMonth
   Order by
   t.CreatedMonth